# Why does external css doesnt work on svg elements in IE using D3

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, rect

As the title says: Why does external css doesnt work on svg elements in IE using D3.

Im using the D3 libary for creating `rect` from a json file.
My json file can contain 100+ `rect` with diffrent x and y cords.
To keep the json file small as possible i have a external css file with the `width`, `height`, `fill` and `stroke`.

It works in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox.

Here is a Fiddle example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f4ax25n/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

width and height are not CSS properties in SVG 1.1 they are attributes which cannot be set with CSS.

Chrome (and Chrome clones such as Opera) supports them as CSS properties since that's what SVG 2 proposes. No other UA supports them as CSS properties currently.

Comment: Thanks this solved it for me and make things a bit more clear for me. i can keep the fill and stroke in a external css file. everything working fine now.  i must be confused with the normal css width and height.